# 't Hooft anomaly implies spontaneous symmetry breaking?

Tags: symmetry-breaking, quantum-anomalies

It isn't clear to me why an 't Hooft anomaly implies spontaneous symmetry breaking. I would like to see an argument which shows this.

The most I can say about this scenario is that if the symmetry is spontaneously broken, then the ground state transforms non-trivially under said symmetry. This creates problems when trying to gauge the symmetry, since gauging it requires that all physical states are invariant under the symmetry. This suggests that gauging the symmetry will produce an 't Hooft anomaly.

This is the converse of the statement that is usually made, so I expect that my reasoning is not completely accurate.

Is there a more rigorous understanding of this fact? If so I would love to see it!

**Edit**

It's clear from AccidentalFourierTransform's comments that I had a misconception about this. I must have not understood completely the papers I had found which used 't Hooft anomalies to either show or **suggest** spontaneous symmetry breaking.

Comment: Anomaly does not imply SSB. There are many examples of systems with anomalous symmetries which are also realized by the vacuum. A very explicit example given by [Seiberg et al](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.03258), where e.g. the theory is invariant under time-reversal, this symmetry is anomalous, and the ground state is also time-reversal symmetric (and nicely reproduces the anomaly, a fact that plays an important role in that paper).

Comment: Interesting. I thought though that 't Hooft anomalies were frequently used to show spontaneous symmetry breaking. In fact the same time reversal symmetry is shown to be broken in 4d $SU(N)$ theory at $\theta=\pi$ by using 't Hooft anomalies in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.00501.pdf

Comment: The point is that anomalies imply non-trivial infrared. The infrared could be gapless (i.e., massless degrees of freedom, e.g. Goldstone particles), but it could also be gapped (i.e., topological degrees of freedom, e.g. Goldstone "strings", as in SSB of a one-form symmetry). Anomalies only imply non-trivial infrared; it doesn't tell you what "non-trivial" means. It could be SSB, but it could also be other more exotic alternatives. You can only conclude that there is not a unique gapped vacuum. You cannot conclude that a symmetry broke spontaneously.

Comment: Okay, thank you for that clarification.

Comment: No problem. BTW, not sure why you got a downvote, this is a perfectly reasonable question. The whole point of 't Hooft original computation is to try and argue that the chiral symmetry is broken: it is even in the title!

Comment: So, is the converse of this statement true? SSB implies anomaly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108763/discussion-between-lucashwindowwasher-and-accidentalfouriertransform).